# Angular 10: service undefined error when doing click function from other component

Tags: angular-services, angular10

I am facing a service undefined error. I am doing a click function from a shared component and after that, I called a service but that service showing undefined in the component.
I added the service in the app module and in providers also. Still, I am facing the issue. Anyone help me to sort that issue.

Method:

```
approveReject(data,action,type){
    
    console.log(data, action, type);

    let endpoint;
    let reqData;
    if( type.toLowerCase() == 'advertiser'){
      if(action.toLowerCase() == 'approve'){
        endpoint = 'advActivate';       
      }else{
        endpoint = 'advReject';
      }
      reqData = {         
        guid:data.guid,
        userid:data.userid,
        id:data.id,
      }
      
    }else if(type.toLowerCase() == 'publisher'){
      if(action.toLowerCase() == 'approve'){
        endpoint = 'pubActivate';
      }else{
        endpoint = 'pubReject';
      }
    }
    console.log('**********');
    console.log(this.apiservice);
   
    this.apiservice.fullLoader(true);
    this.apiservice.post(endpoint, reqData).subscribe((res) => {
      this.apiservice.fullLoader(false)
        console.log("res->",res)
        if(res.msg.toLowerCase() == 'ok' && res.error_code == 0){
          this.apiservice.alertMessage('success', type.toLowerCase()+''+action.toLowerCase()+'ed  Successfully');
        }
    },err => {
      this.apiservice.fullLoader(false)
      this.apiservice.alertMessage('danger', 'Failed to '+action.toLowerCase()+''+type.toLowerCase()+'Please Try again');
    })
   
  }
```

Click component html in shared component:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <ng-container *ngIf="col.field != 'actions';else alink">
                {{data[col.field]}}
            </ng-container>
                
            <ng-container *ngIf="col.field == 'actions'" #alink>
                
                <a  *ngFor="let linkData of data[col.field]" href="javascript:;"  title="{{linkData.name}}" [appHasRole]="linkData.hasRole" (click)="linkData.action(data,linkData.name,linkData.type)"><i class="{{linkData.icon}}"></i>                    
                </a>
            </ng-container>
        </td>       
    </tr>
   </ng-template>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullLoader' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor of your component in which you are trying to trigger the click?

Comment: @FyZ1K any answers or clues for this?

Comment: Well only thing I could think of right now is to try passing the apiservice in to the click method as an argument -> approveReject( apiService ,data,action,type) just to test if this works.. Thing is it get's real messy when handling with the built in component factory resolver when doing multiple loops (ngFor) inside another... Another approach might be splitting up the html code to seperate component fragments (one that does one ngfor and another seperate component that does the other ngfor) to narrow down the issue..

Comment: will check...any other solutions other than this?

Comment: @FyZ1K its working tried using first one approveReject( apiService ,data,action,type)..Any drawback of this method?

Comment: I would need more information on how you retrieve your data (what type?) and where and how do you store the data which you are using in the ngFor loop.. Looks like a grid/table based structure to me..

Comment: and to answer your question about drawbacks, I'll put it like this: To enlighten you with the approach you're doing by passing the service in to the Method as a parameter:

Of course you will have a sufficient drawback the bigger your apiService gets. Neitherless if the service is just thought for CRUD operations it might run up untill a certain extinction point has been reached (for example if you put a lot of functions and data storages in it) and it is certainly not the way to do things.

Comment: @FyZ1K its dynamic component for table